# Have I broken jQuery regex?

Tags: jquery, regex, email, input

I did this on my server and it only seemed to check the first char of the entry.
I then tried to put it on jsFiddle to example and test it, but i've no idea how to get jsFiddle working as there seems to be no response on there.
https://jsfiddle.net/bw906rLt/

I have tried many examples ive found on stackoverflow, but each time it only tests the first letter

```
<input id="email" onKeyUp="testEmail(this);">
<span id="a">answer</span>

function testEmail(el) {
    var em = $(el).val();
    if (validate(em)) {
        $("#a").html("valid");
    } else {
        $("#a").html("invalid");
    }
}

function validate(em) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_@])/;
    return regex.test(em);
}
```

This is a simple example of what I am doing, but it doesnt work.
on my server it respond valid for 'a', invalid for '(' yet valid for 'a('.

I have read several things on regex but I am at a miss here somwhere

Totally baffles me

Comment: `up` is not defined at https://jsfiddle.net/bw906rLt/ ?

Comment: just as an evil reminder http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat the char class one or more times and then add end of the line anchor.

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_@]+$/;
```

or

```
var regex = /^[\w@]+$/;
```

> on my server it respond valid for 'a', invalid for '(' yet valid for 'a('. Why?

`^([a-zA-Z0-9_@])` regex matches a single char at the start which must be a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or _ or @ . So `a` got matched, `(` won't get matched because `(` is not present inside the char class. Above regex matches `a(` because `a-z` inside the char class matches the starting `a`, so it returns true.

Comment: saw you first comment and changed it to that and it worked, thank you and will tick, then saw your explanation, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Appear `onKeyUp` handler set as `up` at

`onKeyUp="up(this);`

though `up` not appear defined ?

Try substituting `.keyup()` for setting event handler at `html` , calling `testEmail` as handler for `.keyup()` , `event` for `el` for `el` within `testEmail` , where `event` is `keyup` event , `event.target` is `input` element

html

```
<input id="email"> <span id="a">answer</span>
```

js

```
$(function() {

function testEmail(event) {
    var em = $(event.target).val();
    if (validate(em)) {
        $("#a").html("valid");
    } else {
        $("#a").html("invalid");
    }    
}

function validate(em) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_@])/;
    return regex.test(em);
}

$("#email").keyup(testEmail);

});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bw906rLt/2/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, have made a simple function to get what I want now, thanks again.

```
 <input onKeyUp="testEmailChars"><span id="a"></span>

 function testEmailChars(el){
    var email = $(el).val();
    if ( /^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]+$/.test(email)==true ){
        $("#a").html("valid");
    } else {
        $("#a").html("not valid");
    }
}
```